# Override require to start from root and check node modules without changing it's name

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, dependencies, require

I'm trying to share my client and server code and I want a tidy way of requiring my dependencies.

I'm currently using webpack as my build tool and I've set it to resolve to my assets/js folder so my dependencies for the client look something like this:

```
require('validators/login.js');
```

I'd like to share the exact same code across the server, but I don't want to put if statements in to check if it's the server or client that's doing the requiring so I can do something like

```
if server
  rootRequire..
else
  require
```

What i'd like is for the server to use require like the client does and start from the root directory, but I also don't want to strip it of its functionality to search the node_modules folder if it doesn't return a result.

I also want this done without placing all my code in the node_modules folder.

Does anyone have some good suggestions for how to override require properly? I've read most of the hacky solutions like using symlinks or placing things in node_modules and I'm not looking for those answers, I'd like something that is clean and actually overrides require properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've come up with a solution I'm reasonably happy with, figured I'd share it with anyone who else needed an answer.

```
var module = require('module');
var baseRequire = module.prototype.require;

module.prototype.require = function()
{
    // Add any extra paths here...
    var extraPaths = [
        __dirname
    ];

    for (var i = 0, len = extraPaths.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (this.paths.indexOf(extraPaths[i]) == -1) {
            this.paths.push(extraPaths[i])
        }
    }

    return baseRequire.apply(this, arguments);
};
```